# Attribute binding using emberjs, handlebar, with jquery draggable

Tags: jquery, data-binding, jquery-ui-draggable, ember.js, handlebars.js

Attribute binding emberjs jquery draggable handlebar

I have an emberJS object:

```
randomsticker= Sticker.create({
                id : 2,
                title : "someeditable value by binding",
                top : 100,
                left : 200
            });
```

This has a handlebar view template in the html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sticker_view">
    <article class = 'sticker'>
            {{editablefield sticker.title}}
    </article>
</script>
```

So I create this using the generator class:

```
concrete_view = Ember.View.create({
        templateName : 'sticker_view',
        sticker : randomsticker
});
concrete_view.appendTo('somepartofwebpage');
```

I make it draggable using jquery-ui .draggable() method:

```
$('sticker').draggable();
```

I made want to make the sticker draggable the way it sync's with the randomsticker model-object values.
My question is what is the simplest/most elegant way to do this?

The problem is that I guess emberjs can not see the changes, what jQuery makes in the attribute field. 
I tried to bind it to style like I forget about top&left values, Im only storing style (that's not the most elegant way and it also does not bind from view to model.)

```
 randomsticker= Sticker.create({
            id : 2,
            title : "someeditable value by binding",
            style: "top:50px; left:100px;"
        });
```

The template looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sticker_view">
    <article class = 'sticker' {{bindAttr style="sticker.style"}}>
            {{editablefield sticker.title}}
    </article>
</script>
```

I also found a library what's supposed to bind styles, but it also does not work backwards

https://github.com/yderidde/bindstyle-ember-helper

This did not work also.
I tried to get it with a computed property like this:

```
        style : Ember.computed(function() {
            return "top:" + this.get('top') + "px;left:" + this.get('left')
                    + 'px;';
        }).property('top', 'left'),
```

I guess this is what I need on the long run, writing a complex value setter, but I could not figure out, how to get jquery to triger the original object's value-change event.

So I was thinking what to write in the draggable part, to get it work?

```
$('sticker').draggable({ 
    stop: function(){ //get the values refreshed, but how? }
});
```

( I could look the object up from other place, but I feel that I do not want that... )
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (but still not perfect) I found so far, is to bind the mouseUp event to a view class.

So I create the template a little different:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sticker_view">
    <article class = 'sticker'>
         {{#view App.StickerView}}
            {{editablefield sticker.title}}
         {{/view}}
    </article>
</script>
```

After this is done, I have to create that class:

```
App.StickerView = Ember.View.extend({

    mouseUp: function(event){   
        var emberStickerObj = this.get('content');  // get the emberobj     
        var pos = $(event.target).position();   // ideapos
        emberStickerObj.set('top',pos.top);
        emberStickerObj.set('left',pos.left);
    }
});
```

The event is trigered on the draggable, when I release it it will call the mouseUp.

The bad part is: it wont refresh, if I pull the draggable out from the window, what happens sometimes...